# Setting Date format for JQuery date picker clears the initial date value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-formatting

I'm trying to set format for the date picker but it clears the default value in the field.

```js
$(".date").datepicker();
// While trying to format (the same format as mentioned above 'dd-mm-yy'), the field value is cleared on execution of below code
$('.date').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Kindly note that format of the value here is 'dd-mm-yy' -->
  <p>Date: <input class='date' type="text" value="31-12-2016"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Already I have read through these posts
|[JQuery UI Datepicker date format issue with initial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427504/jquery-ui-datepicker-date-format-issue-with-initial-value)|[Why does constructing a JQuery UI Datepicker clear the field's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468547/why-does-constructing-a-jquery-ui-datepicker-clear-the-fields-value)|[Setting 'option' on jqueryui DatePicker clears the textbox's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292472/setting-option-on-jqueryui-datepicker-clears-the-textboxs-value)

All states that the existing value should match date picker's format which I'm trying to set. Looks like I'm clean in that.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Could you  set the date format in the initialization of datepicker instead of later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working! I set the date format on initialization of the datepicker. Now the default value is retained and date format is also working.

@Twisty Thanks for throwing light on this

```js
//Setting the format on initialisation
$(".date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

// While trying to format (the same format as mentioned above 'dd-mm-yy'), the field value is cleared on execution of below code

//$('.date').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Kindly note that format of the value here is 'dd-mm-yy' -->
  <p>Date: <input class='date' type="text" value="31-12-2016"></p>
</body>

</html>
```